# One wildcard SSL certificate to work on my subdomain sites using wildcard subdomains, and on my single subdomain site not using the wildcard subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, https, subdomain

I have a WordPress multisite on domain mysite.com, this allows you to create multiple sub domain sites (test1.example.com, test2.example.com etc).
It uses wildcard subdomains where you add a * in cpanel > subdomains. Here is the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I can configure a wildcard SSL certificate to work for this, all subdomains on this WordPress network will have https.

I also have a non-WordPress site running on the same domain: (myothersite.mysite.com). This site doesn't use wildcard subdomains, I have to set up the subdomain name in cPanel > subdomains by adding the subdomain 'myothersite', as it won't work with the * (wildcard subdomain).

My question is, is there a configuration that will allow me to use the same wildcard SSL certificate on my non WordPress site?

Because at the moment, I need 2 SSL certificates. I need a wildcard SSL certificate which handles all the subdomains on my WordPress multisite, and a single SSL certificate for my non WordPress subdomain site.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: just copy the SSL to the other site's ssl config

Answer (score 0):

If your wildcard subdomains refer a same root domain then you can secure all your subdomains with a single Wildcard SSL certificates. Moreover, major certificate authorities offer unlimited server licenses with their wildcard certificate, so you can apply a same certificate on multiple servers.

- www.example.com (WordPress Multisite Network)
- test1.example.com (WordPress Multisite Network)
- test2.example.com (WordPress Multisite Network)
- test3.example.com (non-WordPress Site)

It is recommended to enable force HTTP to HTTPS through domain mapping settings to enhance users trust and robust security. You should refer this article for further details - https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-use-an-ssl-certificate-for-wordpress-multisite-network